# OpenMP runtime conditional GPU target kernel execution

Tags: fortran, gpu, openmp

Is there a syntax that allows for conditional kernel execution on a device (GPU) or host based on the status of that condition at run time?

Here is a sample fortran code that can easily toggle the device data clauses based on the status of the variable `onGPU`

However, the kernel seems to just abort on the condition being false, and is never executed on the host. Here is the sample code I am looking at.

```
program test

  implicit none

  integer :: a,b,c
  logical   ::  onGPU

  real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: array

  onGPU = .false.

  allocate(array(1000,1000,1000))
  array=0.e0

  !$omp target enter data if(onGPU) map(to:array)

  !$omp target teams distribute parallel do collapse(3) schedule (static, 1) &
  !$omp& if(onGPU) &
  !$omp& private(a,b,c)
  do a = 1,1000
     do b = 1,1000
        do c = 1,1000
           array(a,b,c) = 1.e0
        end do
     end do
  end do

  !$omp target update if(onGPU) from(array)

write(*,*) sum(array)/size(array)

end program test
```

The above has very odd behavior that I cant make sense of. And the issue is the device kernel. Removing the if clause from the device kernel and playing around with the data clauses gives the expected behavior. I have also played around with the location of the if() statement in the kernel with no luck.

I am using the IBM fortran compiler for this. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Which compiler version do you use? Did you try different compilers?

Comment: I am using 16.1.1-8, I can try with gcc, though I haven't had good luck doing much with that compiler in the production version of the code this is being implemented in. But I will try and update.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing with developers, it seems this feature is a VERY new feature at the time of this posting, and is yet to be implemented in most compilers.

So we wait patiently.